# element that is algebraic over a finite field

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. And let $q = p^{2h}$.
Suppose I know that an element $\alpha \in \overline{ \mathbb{F}_q }$, satisfies $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$. Does this mean that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q$? 
I think the answer is yes, but I can't seem to figure it out... I would appreciate an explanation whether the answer is yes or no.
Thanks!

Comment: If $p=3$, or $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, we can do even better: $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $\alpha$ is contained in *some* quadratic extension of $\mathbb F_p$. But there is only one such extension of $\mathbb F_p$ (in general up to isomorphim, but within a fixed closure it is really unique). So, yes, $\alpha\in\mathbb F_{p^2}\subseteq \mathbb F_q$

Answer (score 0):

If $p=2$ Yes:

$\alpha^{2^2-1}-1=\alpha^3-1=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$. Hence $\alpha\in \Bbb F_{2^2}$.